# global vector C++

Tags: c++, windows, stl, vector, global

Is it possible to have a vector as a global variable is C++?
Like this:

```
class system {...};
vector<system> systems;
```

when I try to compile this I get an error. The compiler I'm using is gcc and I'm compiling as C++.

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: Vector can be made as global. Though I would not recommend to do that without strong reason. what is the error?

Comment: please . give . us . the . error . message

Answer (score 7):

Yes that can like this:

```
#include <vector>

class system{ ... };

std::vector<system> systems;
```

So the vector global var is defined after the definition of the class system. Vector must be included and don't forget std:: before vector (or using namespace std).

Edit:
I just thought of something. There is also a function called system. Try a different class name.

Comment: If you try compiling this code with gcc you get an error.  See my answer about the class name being "system".

Comment: It compiles for me using g++ 4.4.1 (after removing the ...). "system" is not a reserved word in C++, if that is what you are thinking about.

Comment: @Neil, I testing with g++ 3.4.4 under Cygwin.  I know system is not a reserved keyword but for some reason g++ was giving an error on it.

Comment: However, `system` is a function declared in `<stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>`. <i>(I have it listed in Section 19.2 of "C, A Reference Manual" by Harbison and Steele)</i>.  I definitely would choose another name.

Answer (score 6):

`system()` is a c-stdlib function, hence possibly an already defined name, so you can't re-use it.

Re-name it to something else (System?) and post the full error message next time, plz.

Comment: being a standard library function name does not make it a reserved name.  If he has not included <stdlib.h> he should not see "system" in the symbol table.  This seems to be a problem with atleast some versions of g++.  Changing the class name does help in these case - see my answer.

Comment: even though this is true, the error occurs only if you include, somehow, windows.h !!!!

Comment: right.. reserved is bad wording on my part.. I've updated it.

Answer (score 3):

When I compile your code with g++ 3.4.4 under Cygwin I get the following errors:

> test.cpp:8: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list
>   for `template class std::vector'
>
> test.cpp:8: error:   expected a type, got `system'
>
> test.cpp:8: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>
> test.cpp:8: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token

The problem is your class name system, either change the name of the class or use:

`vector<class system> systems`

Comment: remove the header <cstdlib> and check again.

Comment: The only header included was <vector>.

Comment: +1 to counteract the ridiculous down-votes. The keyword `class` can indeed be used to disambiguate a meaning of a symbol. For the potential down-voters: it is customary to leave a comment explaining the vote.

Comment: @avakar: I agree. +1 from me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you declared it in a header file without `extern`

Comment: I didn't down vote you. I must say that this was a valid guess without the error itself. No idea why someone would downvote because of that

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class system{
  // class members
 };

vector<system> v;

int main()
{
   //do something
}
```

It works fine in my g++ compiler. I don't think there should be any problem defining a vector variable globally, but it is not recommended.

Comment: This does not compile in my g++ compiler under cygwin.  The problem is with the class name 'system'.  See my answer.

Comment: There is no problem with 'system' here. I think you might have included the header <cstdlib> and that's why the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is, as often, in windows.h ! "system" is defined in "windows.h" or something included in it. I suppose it's the function to make a system call.